# nginx config (Spring + Angular)

Tags: angular, spring, api, nginx, devops

I need help on how to write my **configuration for nginx**. I want to serve an **Angular** Application that communicates with a **Spring** **API**. I still haven't copied my files to the server so if you can recommend a default location as well, that would be great.

I don't know how to debug this and am not sure if it's going to work. Will this load my 2 config files as well? Do i need to write a server_name in the main config?  Do i need to write an **index** directive somewhere?

I followed a tutorial and saw that I can create 2 config files: 
**`/etc/nginx/sites-available/api.domain.com.conf`**:

```
server {
        server_name api.domain.com;
        location /domain/api/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

**`/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com.conf;`**

```
server {
        server_name domain.mk www.domain.mk;
        location /domain/app/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

And this is how my main configuration file looks like (I have created symbolic links to the 2 files above in **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/[file]**):

**`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`**:

```
error_log       logs/error.log;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        server {
                listen          80;
                access_log      logs/access.log;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is okay if you use 2 separate files. but you need to configure root where your index.html exists.

```html
server {
        server_name api.domain.com;
        
        root /path/of/your/ui/dist/folder/;
        index index.html index.htm;
        
        location /domain/api/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Restart Nginx server and test it.
Please configure domain name in Angular project environment.json file for redirection.

Comment: Do i need to give root location to angular build files in the backend configuration? That snippet above is from the API conf.

Also what is the difference between root and location? Am I not specifying the location already?

Thank you for your response and sorry for the questions but all of this is new to me :S